# Using python to print strings between csv values

Tags: python, csv

My overarching goal is to write a Python script that transforms each row of a spreadsheet into a standalone markdown file, using each column as a value in the file's YAML header.  Right now, the final `for` loop I've written not only keeps going and going and going… it also doesn't seem to place the values correctly.

```py
import csv

f = open('data.tsv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f, dialect=csv.excel_tab)

date = []
title = []

for column in csv_f:
    date.append(column[0])
    title.append(column[1])

for year in date:
    for citation in title:
        print "---\ndate: %s\ntitle: %s\n---\n\n" % (year, citation)
```

I'm using tab-separated values because some of the fields in my spreadsheet are chunks of text with commas. So ideally, the script should output something like the following (I figured I'd tackle splitting this output into individual markdown files later. One thing at a time):

```
---
date: 2015
title: foo
---

---
date: 2016
title: bar
---
```

But instead I getting misplaced values and output that never ends. I'm obviously learning as I go along here, so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you gave us the data you are having problems with.

Comment: Try using [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) in the for loop: ```for cit, year in zip(title, date): ...```

Comment: This did it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
with open('data.tsv', newline='') as f:
    csv_f = csv.reader(f, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
    for column in csv_f:
        year, citation = column # column is a list, unpack them directly
        print "---\ndate: %s\ntitle: %s\n---\n\n" % (year, citation)
```

This is all I can do without the sample CSV file.